# CSS animation not working after replacing text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animate.css

For my website, I am trying to fade out part of a word, replace it, and then fade it back in. I am using animate.css to do this along with jquery.

HTML

```
      <h1>D<span id="span-header">iscover</span></h1>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#span-header").addClass("animated fadeOut");
setTimeout(function() {
   var newText = $("#span-header").text().replace("iscover", "ispicio");
   $("#span-header").text(newText);
}, 700);
$("#span-header").addClass("animated fadeIn");
```

What it is doing is fading out and replacing the text but it does not fade back in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle? Also, it seems there's a mismatch in your IDs.

Comment: You might have to remove the `fadeOut` class before adding the `fadIn` class depending on how your css is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st**: you need to Move the code for `.addClass("fadeIn")` inside `setTimeout` call back function

**2nd**: use `.removeClass('fadeOut')` to remove `fadeOut` class before adding `fadeIn` class

**Demo**

```
$("#span-header").addClass("animated fadeOut");
setTimeout(function() {
   var newText = $("#span-header").text().replace("iscover", "ispicio");
   $("#span-header").text(newText);
   $("#span-header").removeClass('fadeOut').addClass("fadeIn");
}, 700);
```